# Order a text field numerically in views

Tags: 7, views

I need to reorder my views results before display it.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field_numero.field_numero_value AS commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field, node.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_magazine} field_data_field_magazine ON node.nid = field_data_field_magazine.entity_id AND (field_data_field_magazine.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_magazine.deleted = '0')
INNER JOIN {commerce_product} commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine ON field_data_field_magazine.field_magazine_product_id = commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine.product_id
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_tipo} field_data_field_tipo ON node.nid = field_data_field_tipo.entity_id AND (field_data_field_tipo.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_tipo.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_numero} commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field_numero ON commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine.product_id = commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field_numero.entity_id AND (commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field_numero.entity_type = 'commerce_product' AND commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field_numero.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('magazine')) AND (field_data_field_tipo.field_tipo_value IN  ('rivista', 'dvd')) ))
ORDER BY commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field ASC
```

and it works fine but I need the same view with a different ordering

```
ORDER BY ABS(commerce_product_field_data_field_magazine__field_data_field)
```

because the result's now order like

```
1 10 11 2 3 4 ..
```

but I need

```
1 2 3 4 10 11 ..
```

How can I achieve this changing of ordering?

ps_ I can't change the text field type to int because I have some value like '5-6'

Comment: MySQL ABS cannot work on strings like "5-6". It operates only on numbers. What you want will always be impossible on the data you have, by design. Please edit your question to provide requirements that are technically possible :)

Comment: I tryed on my db and ABS works fine ^^

Comment: It is not *bound* to fail, it's just unsafe and it may return unexpected result or make database to refuse to process your query.

Comment: What Drupal version? Please tag your question with the right Drupal version.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use views instead?
The [Views Natural Sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_natural_sort) module may help you

Otherwise, in drupal 7 you can go with

```
$query->orderby( 'CAST(n.title AS SIGNED)', 'ASC');
```

Check also  [CAST Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: nice solution! works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

for the Drupal8 we can do like:

```
$query->addExpression('CAST(n.title AS SIGNED)', 'title_as_int');
$query->orderby( 'title_as_int', 'ASC');
```